# Combining values from two arrays with same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = Array ( [1] => ab [2] => cd [at] => ef )
$arr2 = Array ( [1] => gh [2] => ij [at] => kl )
```

I want to combine these two arrays to this array:

```
$arr3 = Array ( [1] => ab-gh [2] => cd-ij [at] => ef-kl )
```

The keys are the same in the two arrays so I imagine that it is possible to join the values of the arrays with a "-" between like above.

I have googled and tried almost anything (merge, combine, join) but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to write your own algorithm for this. Someone may be kind enough to write it for you, but you'll get better responses if you can provide any attempts you have made.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the keys of one array. Get the values associated with the key from both arrays, combine them, associate the new value to the same key `$arr3`.

Comment: Related page grouping and concatenating indexed arrays: [joining two separate arrays in PHP into one array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49651862/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can guarantee these two arrays will always have the same keys:

```
$arr3 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val1) {
  $val2 = $arr2[$key];
  $arr3[$key] = $val1 . "-" . $val2;
}
```

---

Now, assuming the two have different keys and you want to do a "joined" array with only the keys that exist in both arrays:

```
$arr3 = array();
foreach (array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2)) as $key) {
  $arr3[$key] = $arr1[$key] . "-" . $arr2[$key];
}
```

This is similar to a SQL inner join.

If you want to do a "joined" array with the keys in *either* of the arrays, hyphen-joining only the ones that exist in both:

```
$arr3 = array();
foreach (array_merge(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2)) as $key) {
  if (isset($arr1[$key]) && isset($arr2[$key])) {
    $arr3[$key] = $arr1[$key] . "-" . $arr2[$key];
  } else {
    $arr3[$key] = (isset($arr1[$key]) ? $arr1[$key] : $arr2[$key]);
  }
}
```

This is similar to a SQL outer join.

[Try all of the above online!](https://repl.it/repls/EvilFrayedSkylark)

Comment: I think you should test the presence of `$arr2[$key]` before to use it.

Comment: @Syscall Provided other solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've got two arrays with the same amount of values and the same keys.

This should help:

```
$arr1 = Array ("ab", "cd", "at" => "ef");
$arr2 = Array ("gh", "ij", "at" => "kl");
$combinedArray = array();

function combineValues(array $array1, array $array2)
{
    $array3 = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
         $array3[$key] = $value . "-" . $array2[$key];
    }

    return $array3;
}

$combinedArray = combineValues($arr1, $arr2);
```

I really hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Although accepted answer is perfectly ok, here is a more general solution, that can be used for any number of arrays:

```
$arr1 = [1 => 'ab', 2 => 'cd', 'at' => 'ef'];
$arr2 = [1 => 'gh', 2 => 'ij', 'at' => 'kl'];
$arr3 = [1 => 'mn', 2 => 'op', 'at' => 'qr'];

$arr = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];

$keys = array_intersect(...array_map('array_keys', $arr));

$result = array_combine($keys, array_map(function ($key) use ($arr) {
    return implode('-', array_column($arr, $key));
}, $keys));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5a7353035b4bfcf5c6f1227dc2ccf7343b59fae).