# joining two separate arrays in PHP into one array

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

i have a piece of code that joins two arrays together in PHP like this

```
    $array_1=[1,2,3,4]; //input 1
    $array_2= ["a","b","c","d"];//input 2
    $array_3= ["1 a", "2 b", "3 c", "4 d"]; //this is how my final array should look like
```

i tried using array merge but it did not do what i wanted it to do 
is there another function i can use to do this.

so basically i am trying to get the numbers from the `array 1` and letters from the `array 2` and join it together in `array 3`
in to a single array

Comment: Curly braces aren't arrays? ***Edit***: I stand corrected, as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) - `Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).`

Comment: i have edited my code please check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just `map` the 2 arrays

```
$array_1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array_2 = array('a','b','c','d');

$array_3 = array_map(function($a1, $a2) {
    return $a1 . " " . $a2;
}, $array_1, $array_2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $array_3 );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 a
    [1] => 2 b
    [2] => 3 c
    [3] => 4 d
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$array_1=[1,2,3,4]; //input 1
$array_2= ['a','b','c','d'];//input 2

for($i=0;$i<count($array_1);$i++){
    $newArray[]=$array_1[$i].' '.$array_2[$i];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 a
    [1] => 2 b
    [2] => 3 c
    [3] => 4 d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need. I assume that both of arrays contains equal quantity of elements.

```
function merge($array1, $array2) {
    $retArray = [];

    foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {
        $retArray[] = $value . ' ' . $array2[$index];
    }

    return $retArray;
}

$array_1 = [1,2,3,4];
$array_2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
$array_3 = merge($array_1, $array_2);

var_dump($array_3);
```

The result is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1 a"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "2 b"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "3 c"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "4 d"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_1=[1,2,3,4];
$array_2= ["a","b","c","d"];
$array_3 = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < min(count($array_1), count($array_2)); $i++) {
    array_push($array_3, sprintf("%d %s", $array_1[$i], $array_2[$i]));
}
var_dump($array_3);
```